# Method for populating ListViewSubItems

Tags: vb.net

This is my current method for populating the sub-items of `ListView` controls. I like this method for two reasons...

1) I don't have to keep up with the display order of the columns.

2) If I enable column re-ordering, I don't have to change anything with the code.

So, the question is... Is this a good approach? Can it be improved?

*Note: I'm not too happy about declaring `Result As Object`. It seems like there should be a better way to handle that, but it's the only way I could get it to working.*

```
Private Function RetrieveItem(Of T)(ByVal displayIndex As Integer) As T
    Dim Result As Object = If(GetType(T) Is GetType(ListViewItem), New ListViewItem, New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)
    Select Case displayIndex
        Case ColumnHeader1.DisplayIndex
            Result.Text = "First Item"
            Result.Tag = "First"
        Case (ColumnHeader2.DisplayIndex)
            Result.Text = "Second Column"
            Result.Tag = "Second"
        Case ColumnHeader3.DisplayIndex
            Result.Text = "Third Column"
            Result.Tag = "Third"
        Case ColumnHeader4.DisplayIndex
            Result.Text = "Fourth Column"
            Result.Tag = "Fourth"
    End Select
    Return Result
End Function
```

Example Usage...

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = RetrieveItem(Of ListViewItem)(0)
For i As Integer = 1 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
    item.SubItems.Add(RetrieveItem(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)(i))
Next
ListView1.Items.Add(item)
```

---

Here is the example I came up with using @MarkHurd's suggestion of using a [`Widening CType Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yf7b9sy7%28VS.80%29.aspx)...

```
Private Class LVI
    Public Name As String
    Public Text As String
    Public Tag As Object
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal text As String, ByVal tag As Object)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Text = text
        Me.Tag = tag
    End Sub
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal item As LVI) As ListViewItem
        Dim Result As New ListViewItem(item.Text)
        Result.Name = item.Name
        Result.Tag = item.Tag
        Return Result
    End Operator
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal item As LVI) As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
        Dim Result As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
        Result.Text = item.Text
        Result.Name = item.Name
        Result.Tag = item.Tag
        Return Result
    End Operator
End Class

Private Function RetrieveItem(ByVal index As Integer) As LVI
    Select Case index
        Case ColumnHeader1.DisplayIndex : Return New LVI("1", "First Column", "one")
        Case ColumnHeader2.DisplayIndex : Return New LVI("2", "Second Column", "two")
        Case ColumnHeader3.DisplayIndex : Return New LVI("3", "Third Column", "three")
        Case ColumnHeader4.DisplayIndex : Return New LVI("4", "Fourth Column", "four")
        Case Else : Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

Example usage...

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = RetrieveItem(0)
For i As Integer = 1 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
    item.SubItems.Add(RetrieveItem(i))
Next
ListView1.Items.Add(item)
```

I like both of these approaches, but I feel like the first is shorter and easier to implement, so I lean towards the first option.

Comment: What's wrong with your expected problem of editing the font color? How is this not possible with your code (with obvious changes to actually *try* something, since your code does not seem to do anything with font color ATM)?

Comment: @Gaffi, In the original code you would have had to return a custom structure, or class, which I think would be tedious, or make a new function for each property. I have changed the code to use Generic Types instead which should overcome that problem.

Comment: "I'm not too happy about declaring `Result As Object`." That's not your fault: Microsoft should have at least defined an interface that both `ListViewItem` and `ListViewSubItem` implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the late bound `.Text` and `.Tag` you could just create your own private type, say `LVI`, containing these two properties and implicit `Widening` `CType` operators for `ListViewItem` and `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem`. Then the `Result As New LVI` can be converted on return using `Return CType(CTypeDynamic(Result, GetType(T)), T)` in the latest VB.NET.

Without `CTypeDynamic` I don't have a working solution yet.

Comment: I was previously unaware of [`Widening CType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yf7b9sy7%28VS.80%29.aspx). Your suggestion looks promising... I think when I get a chance, I will experiment with that approach and see how it turns out. If I like it, I'll post it as an addendum to my question.